# API to get record level and access level privileges of a user

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

Is there any API through which I can get a user's access level and record level privileges? First, I want to check if a user has access to a specific entity, and then I want to check what documents a user can access out of all the records in that entity.

Answer (score 0):

I think your dynamics crm enviornment is either 2011 or 2013.

If it was dynamics 365 (9.0) and above there is an webapi function which you could call and get extact rights for a particualr record.

But in 2011 or 2013, you will have to first find out which privilige you are looking for and then user c# Dynamics SDK to find out if user has that privilige(right)

[Take a look at this article](https://www.crmanswers.net/2014/09/check-if-user-has-specific-privilege.html)

Comment: did you manged to solve it?